# WP REST API V2 didint work

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I installed [JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)
and it worked properly ,but its an old version

then I installed [WordPress REST API (Version 2)](http://v2.wp-api.org/)
and it didnt make any result and just show this for my request:

"Unexpected '<' "

Comment: The REST API is now build directly into WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ - No need to install any plugins

Comment: @Und3rTow whats different?  it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

in  wp-includes/meta.php file

we should add this code :

```
function get_registered_meta_keys( $object_type ) {
global $wp_meta_keys;

if ( ! is_array( $wp_meta_keys ) || ! isset( $wp_meta_keys[ $object_type ] ) ) {
    return array();
}

return $wp_meta_keys[ $object_type ];
}
```